# Rails Collection_Select with formatted output

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a select box that I want to populate with all 'Users' in the system. However I wish the 'name' for the current user to display as 'Myself'.

I have this so far.

```
f.collection_select(:author, User.all, :id, :name)
```

Which gives me:

```
<select id="product_author" name="product[author]">
    <option value="1">Adam</option>
    <option value="2">David</option>
    <option value="3">Gary</option>
    <option value="4">Tom</option>
</select>
```

What I hope to achieve where, in this example, the current user is Gary (3):

```
<select id="product_author" name="product[author]">
    <option value="1">Adam</option>
    <option value="2">David</option>
    <option value="3">Myself</option>
    <option value="4">Tom</option>
</select>
```

I've attempted trying to apply a map to the User.all statement like so:

```
User.all.map {|a| [((a.name==current_user.name)? 'Myself' : a.name),a.id]}
```

But end up getting the following error:

```
undefined method `name' for ["Adam", 1]:Array
```

Answer (score 1):

I Think you need to change like this

```
 User.all.map {|a| [(a.name == current_user.name ? 'Myself' : a.name),a.id]}
```

Comment: I'd tried this originally but it didn't seem to work, coming back with errors saying 'undefined method 'name' for ['Adam', 1]. I managed to get around this problem by using :first and :second to select the properties e.g. f.collection_select(:author, User.all.map {|a| [((a.name==current_user.name)? 'Myself' : a.name),a.id]}, :second, :first)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a select tag:

`f.select("author", User.all.map {|a| [((a.name==current_user.name)? 'Myself' : a.name),a.id]} , { include_blank: true })`

Or use options_for_select:

`f.collection_select(:author, options_for_select(User.all.map {|a| [((a.name==current_user.name)? 'Myself' : a.name),a.id]}))`

Further reading [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html).